# Creating a new list from another one and filling missing values by repeating

Tags: python, list, repeat

I have two lists, one contains the working days, the other one contains the fees corresponding to the working days:

```
wd = [1, 4, 5, 6]
fees = [1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
```

I need a third list with all workdays, filling up fees in the workdays that do not have fees with fees from the previous day:

```
result = [1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
correspDay = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I code this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by building a dictionary to be able to look up fees by day:

```
>>> wd = [1,4,5,6]
>>> fees = [1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
>>> fee_dict = dict(zip(wd, fees))
```

Then build `correspDay` with a simple `range`:

```
>>> correspDay = list(range(1, 7))
```

and build `result` by iterating over `correspDay`, using `fee_dict` to look up the fees and using the last entry when `fee_dict` comes up empty:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in correspDay:
...     result.append(fee_dict.get(i) or result[-1])
...
>>> result
[1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
```

Comment: Guys, I will need a second result with the original workdays repeating, like this: result2 = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Create `result2` and append to it in the same loop that builds `result`.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the values in a dictionary, then loop through the days of the week (1-7) checking if we already have a value for that day. If you do have a value for that day store it incase the next day doesn't have a value. If there isn't a value create an item in the dictionary with a key for that day and a value of the last fee.
At the end I have sorted the list but there is no real reason to do this other than to make the output easier to read

```
fees_dict = {1: 1.44, 4: 1.17, 5: 1.21, 6: 1.26}
last_fee = 0
for i in range(1, 8):
    if i in fees_dict:
        last_fee = fees_dict[i]
    else:
        fees_dict[i] = last_fee

sorted_fees_dict = dict(sorted(fees_dict.items()))
print(sorted_fees_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`feeMap` maps `days` to `fee` that has to be paid `prev` is used to store the previous value(fee).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

wd = [1,4,5,6]
fees = [1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]

corresDay = list(range(1, 6))

feeMap = dict()
index = 0

for index, day in enumerate(wd):
    feeMap[day] = fees[index]

prev = None
for day in range(1, 6):
    if day not in feeMap.keys():
        feeMap[day] = prev
    else:
        prev = feeMap[day]
feeMap = sorted(feeMap.items())

print(feeMap)
```

## output:

```
$ ./working_days.py 
[(1, 1.44), (2, 1.44), (3, 1.44), (4, 1.17), (5, 1.21), (6, 1.26)]
```

Comment: Guys, I will need a second result with the original workdays repeating, like this:

result2 = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything I saw the good people above and I try to make it more clear for you.

```
wd = [1,4,5,6]
fees = [1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
fee_dict = dict(zip(wd, fees))
correspDay = list(range(1,8))
result = []
for i in correspDay:
    result.append(fee_dict.get(i) or result[-1])
```

I just add this line to make the output in dictionary

```
result = dict(zip(correspDay, result))
```

output:

```
{1: 1.44, 2: 1.44, 3: 1.44, 4: 1.17, 5: 1.21, 6: 1.26, 7: 1.26}
```

Comment: How can I get this?  result2 = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: I don't understand you explain more.
what did you mean by result2
and the number is it wd or fees?

Comment: It is the wd, repeating it at the same logic as fees repetition.