# Creating new Python lists from dic and filling missing values by repeating

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, repeat

guys. I'm a beginner in Python and I'm not able to do simples things.

I have a dictionary with workday and fees:

```
    fees_dict = {1: 1.44, 4: 1.17, 5: 1.21, 6: 1.26}
```

I need one list filling the workdays that do not have fees by repeating the previous day's fee and another list repeating the workday correspondent those fees:

```
     result1 = [1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 1.17, 1.21, 1.26]
     result2 = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992622/creating-a-new-list-from-another-one-and-filling-missing-values-by-repeating ?

Comment: I need add the result2.