# Filling numbers in the pyhon list

Tags: python, list, loops, numbers, repeat

I need help to fill the next positions in the python list with the previous number until the position reaches the next number, this number will be repeated until reaches the next and the new list will have *len 10*, the same size as the last value from *"numbers"*.

These numbers will replace [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 10], indeed.

```
    numbers = [1, 4, 6, 10]
    out = [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10]
```

Comment: How's that different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992622/creating-a-new-list-from-another-one-and-filling-missing-values-by-repeating ?

Comment: I need to repeat the numbers (workday there), the other question resolutions only are fit for a dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: you can use `zip()` for this `out = []` and later `for start, end in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]): for _ in range(start, end): out.append(start)` or `for start, end in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]): out += [start] * (end-start)` and at the end `out.append(numbers[-1])`